# using two observes to update one EditText

Tags: java, android, observable, android-livedata, observers

i have this EditText:

```
binding.creditAndCash.setText(" cash: " + cash + "₪" + " cerdit: " + getInputOne + "₪");
```

with two parms: cash and getInputOne.
in the Acticity i have the observes:

```
        viewModel.getCash().observe(this, new Observer<Double>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(Double aDouble) {
                binding.creditAndCash.setText(" cash: " + cash + "₪" + " cerdit: " + getInputOne + "₪");

            }
        });
        viewModel.getCredit().observe(this, new Observer<Double>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(Double aDouble) {
                binding.creditAndCash.setText(" cash: " + cash + "₪" + " cerdit: " + getInputOne + "₪");

            }
        });
```

the problem is how to update to prams with only one EditText, is it posible?
`

i want to setText with the updates parms i have. the parms as i said is cash and getInputOne..